# What is the websockets server location for this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket.io client code that has been tested to work with the server.

```
<script>

    // create a new websocket
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
    // on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
    socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    var usersList = "<dl>";
    $.each(data.users,function(index,user){
        usersList += "<dt>" + user.user_name + "</dt>\n" +
                     "<dd>" + user.user_description + "\n" +
                        "<figure> <img class='img-polaroid' width='50px' src='" + user.user_img + "' /></figure>"
                     "</dd>";
    });
    usersList += "</dl>";
    $('#container').html(usersList);

    $('time').html('Last Update:' + data.time);
  });
```

I tried to use a simple Web Socket client tester software. The one I am using is the Chrome extension "Simple Web Socket Client".

I need to key in the URL for the Websockets server. I keyed in

```
ws://localhost:8000/notification
```

It did not work. I just got an "undefined" error. What URL should I key in for the Websockets server?

Here are the relevant server code.

```
// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);
var updateSockets = function(data) {
  // adding the time of the last update
  data.time = new Date();
  console.log('Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
  // sending new data to all the sockets connected
  connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
    tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
  });
};
```

EDIT:Both the server and client were developed using socket.io

Comment: Have you tried just entering `http://localhost:8000`? From what I understand socket.io doesn't use the standard web socket protocols, but I'm not an expert on the subject.

Comment: @ Jamie Barker: thanks. Let me use another websocket client. The one I used does not accept any URL that starts with http. Only accepts ws

Comment: @JamieBarker `socket.io` provides an additional protocol on top of (regular) websockets (but with fallbacks to long polling, AJAX, ...). If the server is a regular WS server, `socket.io` most likely won't work.

Comment: @robertklep: Both the server and client were developed using socket.io. Should it work if the server is also based on socket.io?

Comment: any socket.io client that one can test with?

Comment: @user768421 yes, that should work. What exactly is causing the `undefined` error (at which line)? Did you load the `socket.io` client in your HTML?

Comment: Both server and client works fine. I was actually testing the Webserver client app. Wondering if I got the URL wrong.